# No response received with JsonResult in MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 6 in beta6.

In my Startup.cs I have the following code:

```
services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.OutputFormatters.RemoveAll(formatter => formatter.GetType() == typeof(JsonOutputFormatter));
                var jsonOutputFormatter = new JsonOutputFormatter
                {
                    SerializerSettings = { ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }
                };
                o.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, jsonOutputFormatter);
            });
```

In my controller I have:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Get()
{
    var result = new DataTablesResult();
    List<MyClass> myClass = await _Repository.GetListMyClass();

    result.Data = new List<dynamic>(myClass);
    var resultado = new
    {
        data = result.Data.ToArray()
    };

    return Json(resultado);
}
```

But when I run the postman, I get the following message:
[image]

Before I was using Asp.Net MVC in 6 beta 4 and this same code worked.

Any idea what could be wrong?

## UPDATE

My routes:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                // add the new route here.
                routes.MapRoute(name: "config",
                   template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}",
                   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

                routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "configId",
                   template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

                routes.MapRoute(name: "platform",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

                routes.MapRoute(name: "platformByUser",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{userId}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

                // Uncomment the following line to add a route for porting Web API 2 controllers.
                // routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
            });
```

Comment: Set a break point in your action to see if that code is actually getting executed.  That would be the first step to understanding the behavior.

Comment: I assume you are using the basic routes? `localhost/{controller}/{action}/{parameter}` Where Parameter is optional? If so can you show us the actual URL you are accessing...

Comment: @ThomasStringer It was the first thing I did!

Comment: @JamieRees add my routes in the question. The action is being called and the variable `resultado` has value.

Comment: Have you tried changing the returned type to "JsonResult"?

Comment: Yeh, but not work! :(

Comment: have you tried getting the method to return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet) ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the below code, DataTable / dynamic to JSON ???

```
**var result = new DataTablesResult();**

List<MyClass> myClass = await _Repository.GetListMyClass();

**result.Data = new List<dynamic>(myClass);**
var resultado = new
{
    data = result.Data.ToArray()
};
```

It doesn't covert to JSON ... right ?

Comment: so the issue is in JSON serializer .. let dig into the libraries and will come back to u ..

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you set property *ReferenceLoopHandling* to *Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore*. As I know, [the settings for the JSON output formatter and for JsonResult are now separate](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3129).
If MyClass has cycles, an error occurs in Json.net.

> Self referencing loop detected

There are two solutions in this case:

1) Use a custom serialize settings for the controller method:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
return Json(result, settings);
```

2) Configung a shared settings between JsonResult and the formatter in the Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //some configuration

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
}
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return a Json explicitly. Try returning your object directly.
You can limit the output to json with the `[Produces]` attribute if you like, or get advantage of content negotiation for format may be wiser.

```
public async Task<DataTablesResult> Get()
{
    var result = new DataTablesResult();
    List<MyClass> myClass = await _Repository.GetListMyClass();

    result.Data = new List<dynamic>(myClass);
    var resultado = new
    {
        data = result.Data.ToArray()
    };

    return Ok(resultado);
}
```