# JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet Not Working

Tags: datatables, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i am working for JQuery Datatables server side. While creating the json object, to return back, it doesn't allow JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet. If code is exactly same what below is, then i am not able to get data in client side.

HTML :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="EmployeeTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>LastName</th>    
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#EmployeeTable').DataTable({
            "processing" : true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide" : true, // for process in server side
            "filter" : false,    // to disable search box
            "orderMulti" : false,// for disable multiple columns at once
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : "/Employee/GetEmployeeDataTable",
                "type" : "post",
                "datatype" : "json"
            },
            "columns" : [
                        { "data": "LastName", "orderable": true }
                   ]

        });
```

Server Side:

```
   [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult GetEmployeeDataTable()
            {
                // Get Parameters

                //get start(paging start index) and length(page size for paging)
                var draw = Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();
                var start = Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();
                var length = Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();

                //get sort column values
                var sortColumn = Request.Form["columns[" + Request.Form["order[0][column]"].FirstOrDefault()+"][name]"].FirstOrDefault();
                var sortColumnDir = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();

                int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
                int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
                int totalRecords = 0;

                var employees = getDataService.GetAllEmployees().Select(x => new {
                    x.LastName
                }).ToList();
                if(!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
                {
                    employees.OrderBy(x => sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
                }
                totalRecords = employees.Count();
                var data = employees.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();


                var result =  Json(new
            {   draw = draw,
                recordsFiltered = totalRecords,
                recordsTotal = totalRecords,
                data = data
            });
                return result;

            }
```

But if i put like following

```
var result =  Json(new
            {   draw = draw,
                recordsFiltered = totalRecords,
                recordsTotal = totalRecords,
                data = data
            },JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

then i can't find this thing in **mvc core**. Please help me what should i do.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net core, the [`Json` method](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs#L292) does not have an overload which takes `JsonRequestBehavior`. So you may simply call the `Json` method with the data you want to pass.

```
var result =  Json(new
            {   draw = draw,
                recordsFiltered = totalRecords,
                recordsTotal = totalRecords,
                data = data
            });
return result;
```

Comment: What is specifically not working ? Are you getting a compile/runtime error ? what error is it ? What is the exception details ?

Comment: I got solution from
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845430/no-response-received-with-jsonresult-in-mvc-6
Thank you very much